# Google markers at same address not showing all markers

Tags: google-maps

I've been working on this map - http://www.mediwales.com/mapping/test/

It's plotting companies fine and clustering them ok but a problem has arisen with companies in the same building with the same address. It's only showing one company rather than all of them.

How can I get it to display all the companies at the same address?

Markers are geocoded by building name/number, street, city, post code. I'm guessing the markers are there as an building that has 3 companies shows a 3 in the cluster. Yet when you click down to it, it only shows the one company.

UPDATE:

I've managed to get them to offset, but it's offsetting all markers when I only want it to offset if there are more than one markers the same. (Thanks to Casey's answer).

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[

    var customIcons = {
      restaurant: {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png',
        shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
      },
      bar: {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png',
        shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
      }
    };

    function load() {
      var cluster = [];
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.4788, -3.9551),
        zoom: 6,
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
      });
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var min = .999999;
var max = 1.000001;

      // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
      downloadUrl("<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/phpsqlajax_genxml.php ", function(data) {
        var xml = data.responseXML;
        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
          var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
          var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
          var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");



          var offsetLat = markers[i].getAttribute("lat") * (Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
          var offsetLng = markers[i].getAttribute("lng") * (Math.random() * (max - min) + min);



          var point = new google.maps.LatLng(offsetLat, offsetLng);
          var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
          var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: point,
            icon: icon.icon,
            shadow: icon.shadow
          });
          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                        return function() {
                            infowindow.setContent(markers[i].getAttribute("name"));
                            infowindow.open(map, marker);
                        }
                    })(marker, i));
          cluster.push(marker);
        }
        var mc = new MarkerClusterer(map,cluster);
      });
    }

    function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infoWindow.setContent(html);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      });
    }

    function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
      var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
          new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
          new XMLHttpRequest;

      request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
          request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
          callback(request, request.status);
        }
      };

      request.open('GET', url, true);
      request.send(null);
    }

    function doNothing() {}

    //]]>
  </script>

   <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[

    var customIcons = {
      restaurant: {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png',
        shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
      },
      bar: {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png',
        shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
      }
    };

    function load() {
      var cluster = [];
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.4788, -3.9551),
        zoom: 6,
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
      });
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

      // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
      downloadUrl("<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/phpsqlajax_genxml.php ", function(data) {
        var xml = data.responseXML;
        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
          var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
          var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
          var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
          var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
          var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
          var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: point,
            icon: icon.icon,
            shadow: icon.shadow
          });
          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                        return function() {
                            infowindow.setContent(markers[i].getAttribute("name"));
                            infowindow.open(map, marker);
                        }
                    })(marker, i));
          cluster.push(marker);
        }
        var mc = new MarkerClusterer(map,cluster);
      });
    }

    function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infoWindow.setContent(html);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      });
    }

    function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
      var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
          new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
          new XMLHttpRequest;

      request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
          request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
          callback(request, request.status);
        }
      };

      request.open('GET', url, true);
      request.send(null);
    }

    function doNothing() {}

    //]]>
  </script>
```

Answer (score 15):

The clusterer is displaying correctly. All the markers are being plotted. The problem is that you can only click on the top most marker, making it seem like there is only one marker.

To see the content for coincident markers, you'll have to pass the infowindow contents of the underlying markers to the top most marker.

To do this, first off, keep track of each marker. You are using MarkerClusterer, so the markerClusterer instance will hold each marker. As each geocode result comes back, compare the latlng of that request with all the markers that have already been plotted. You can compare positions using the equals method of the [latlng](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#LatLng) object.

If the new marker matches the position of an existing marker, take the infowindow contents from the first marker and append it to the new marker's infowindow contents. This way, when you click on the top most marker (the second company), it will show information from both companies. If there are more than two companies, you'll need to grab the infowindow contents for all the matching markers. This method will also allow the marker clusterer to still display the correct number of markers.

[Here](http://maps.caseypthomas.org/ex/MarkerClustererPlus/exCoincidentMarkers_SharedInfowindow_wGeocoding.html) is a working example and the javascript code. The first and second addresses are the same. When you click the marker for 2, it will show "2 & 1".

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var map;

//marker clusterer
var mc;
var mcOptions = {gridSize: 20, maxZoom: 17};

//global infowindow
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

//geocoder
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder(); 

var address = new Array("1000 Market St, Philadelphia, PA","1000 Market St, Philadelphia, PA","1002 Market St, Philadelphia, PA","1004 Market St, Philadelphia, PA");
var content = new Array("1","2","3","4");

function createMarker(latlng,text) {

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng
    });

    ///get array of markers currently in cluster
    var allMarkers = mc.getMarkers();

    //check to see if any of the existing markers match the latlng of the new marker
    if (allMarkers.length != 0) {
        for (i=0; i < allMarkers.length; i++) {
            var currentMarker = allMarkers[i];
            var pos = currentMarker.getPosition();

            if (latlng.equals(pos)) {
                text = text + " & " + content[i];
            }

        }
    }

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.close();
        infowindow.setContent(text);
        infowindow.open(map,marker);
    });

    return marker;
}

function geocodeAddress(address,i) {

    geocoder.geocode( {'address': address}, function(results, status) {

        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

            var marker = createMarker(results[0].geometry.location,content[i]);
            mc.addMarker(marker);

        } else { 
            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status); 
        } 
    });
}

function initialize(){

    var options = { 
        zoom: 13, 
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(39.96225,-75.13222), 
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP 
    }; 

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), options); 

    //marker cluster
    mc = new MarkerClusterer(map, [], mcOptions);

    for (i=0; i<address.length; i++) { 
        geocodeAddress(address[i],i);
    }

}       
</script>
```

**EDIT: Response to comment**

Alternatively, you could nudge coincident markers by applying a small (random number between .999999 and 1.000001, for instance) multiplier to the position of each coincident marker. [Here](http://maps.caseypthomas.org/ex/MarkerClustererPlus/exCoincidentMarkers_NudgeMarker_wGeocoding.html) is an example. This is using the same data as the first example, except, instead of the markers 1 and 2 being placed on top of each other and sharing an infowindow, marker 2 is offset from marker 1. Note that your geocode results are going to be a little less accurate. Relevant code below:

```
//min and max limits for multiplier, for random numbers
//keep the range pretty small, so markers are kept close by
var min = .999999;
var max = 1.000001;

    function createMarker(latlng,text) {

        ///get array of markers currently in cluster
        var allMarkers = mc.getMarkers();

        //final position for marker, could be updated if another marker already exists in same position
        var finalLatLng = latlng;

        //check to see if any of the existing markers match the latlng of the new marker
        if (allMarkers.length != 0) {
            for (i=0; i < allMarkers.length; i++) {
                var existingMarker = allMarkers[i];
                var pos = existingMarker.getPosition();

                //if a marker already exists in the same position as this marker
                if (latlng.equals(pos)) {

                    //update the position of the coincident marker by applying a small multipler to its coordinates
                    var newLat = latlng.lat() * (Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
                    var newLng = latlng.lng() * (Math.random() * (max - min) + min);

                    finalLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(newLat,newLng);

                }                   
            }
        }

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: finalLatLng
        });     

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.close();
            infowindow.setContent(text);
            infowindow.open(map,marker);
        });

        return marker;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Just getting back to this project! Right, would it be possible to offset the markers a tiny bit? The type of companies involved would argue who was top within the info window otherwise (petty I know!).

Comment: Nice work @Casey.  That looks great!

Comment: @Casey Thanks for the reply, how could I work that into my code? I struggle with reworking code like this! Here's my source - view-source:http://www.mediwales.com/mapping/members/

Comment: @Rob Use my example page as a guide. One big difference between our code is that I've pulled my create marker code out from my geocode address code and put it in it's own function called createMarker. You will have to do this as well to get the nudge technique to work.

Comment: @Casey I've had a couple of attempts and can't get it to work... I don't want it to sound like I'm just getting you to do it but I've been trying for the last day.

Comment: @Casey I've added a bounty as you've already gone above and beyond.

Comment: I searched for this simple solution for hours and hours, and got It working with your example. Thanks alot, you're a lifesaver!!

Comment: @Casey I'm finally back on this project!! I've done quite a lot of updates to my code since - I've changed it from geocoding on the fly to geocoding via a database (therefore markers load instantly). Is there any way to incorporate the edited answer into my code, it looks very different. I've updated the link in my question that will show the source.

Comment: @Teamworksdesign.com In the callback of the downloadURL function, replace the marker creation code with the function I've written in the second part of my answer. You'll need to edit it a bit to pass along the additional options you have (shadow, icon, etc). Also, create the MarkerClusterer object before downloadURL is called, and pass the markers into the the MarkerClusterer object individually.

Comment: @Casey Thanks for this great answer.  I found that if I made one small change by using the finalLatLng when tweaking the placement of the pins, I could avoid the scenario where it randomly placed 2 pins on top of each other.  Minor point, but if there are a lot of pins... `if (finalLatLng.equals(pos)) { var newLat = finalLatLng.lat() * (Math.random() * (max - min) + min);var newLng = finalLatLng.lng() * (Math.random() * (max - min) + min); finalLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(newLat,newLng);}`

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with several markers at the exact same lat/long for a sales territory app.  This was a common scenario in my app with multiple customers at the same address, for example customers in the same skyscraper building and thus at the same physical street address.

I found an [alternative answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15600523/google-maps-api-markers-with-duplicate-latitude-and-longitude) with perhaps a better user experience (UX) for overlapping markers.  Thanks to George MacKerron for creating the [OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier](https://github.com/jawj/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier) library.  This JavaScript library for Google Maps v3 overrides the default click behavior for overlapping markers.  The library enables you to configure the offset radius for overlapping (defaults to 20 pixels).

Example Screenshots from http://jawj.github.io/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier/demo.html:

[image: Screenshot of overlapping markers before click]
[image: Screenshot of clicking any of the overlapping markers]
[image: Screenshot of clicking a marker in the "spidered" web of overlapping markers]

Answer (score 0):

I propose to change the above function as follows because the results obtained seem to me better.

```
function adjustMarkerPlace(latlng) {
  ///get array of markers currently in cluster 
  //final position for marker, could be updated if another marker already exists in same position
  var finalLatLng = latlng;

  //check to see if any of the existing markers match the latlng of the new marker
  if (markers.length !== 0) {
      for (let i=0; i < markers.length; i++) {
          var existingMarker = markers[i];
          var pos = existingMarker.getPosition();

          //check if a marker already exists in the same position as this marker
          if (latlng.equals(pos)) {

              //update the position of the coincident marker by applying a small multipler to its coordinates
              var newLat = latlng.lat() + (Math.random() / 10000);
              var newLng = latlng.lng() + (Math.random() / 10000);

              finalLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(newLat,newLng);

          }
      }
  }

  return finalLatLng;
```

}